# What points to a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

As I understand pointers contain the address of data at another memory location?
When an app is running how is the location of pointers kept track of? 
Why bother keeping track of the pointer, why not just directly keep track of address the pointer holds?

Additionally if I have the following code:

```
NSString *string = @"hello";
string = @"bye";
```

I am changing the value stored in the pointer named `string` (is it the pointer that is named `string` or the NSString object?) to the address of the new string ("bye"), right?
So how would I go about changing directly the object stored at the address held by the pointer?

(Also what is the correct terminology to use where I have used "keep track of"?)

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

> Why bother keeping track of the pointer, why not just directly keep
>   track of address the pointer holds?

Object references in objective C are actually pointers, so each time you use an object (such as `NSString`), you use a pointer to it - (`NSString *`)

> I am changing the value stored in the pointer named string (is it the
>   pointer that is named string or the NSString object?) to the address
>   of the new string ("bye"), right?

Right.

> So how would I go about changing directly the object stored at the
>   address held by the pointer?

In the case of such strings, they are immutable, and you can't change them, in case of other objects, you call their methods, or set their properties.

Comment: I don't think I have explained my question well, sorry. I meant why are object reference in objective-c pointers? Why doesn't the app (the runtime?) use the addresses of the actual objects, rather than the addresses of the pointers to the objects? Also when you do `string = @"bye"` you are changing the contents of the pointer, if the pointer is at memory location 1 and the memory location of @"bye" is 2, you are saying `set the contents of memory location 1 to 2` (as I understand you're answer),is there a way to do `set the contents of memory location 2 to <some data>`,without needing pointer?

Comment: `string` is a variable of type pointer to `NSString`. When you do `string = @"bye"` you assign the address of the NSString `@"bye"` to the variable `string`. The usage of pointers allow you to refer to some data from a few places (e.g. class, objects, modules) at once, without the need to copy it. It also simplifies the work with objects behind the scenes and saves a lot of space.

Comment: Surely instead of pointers you can just use the address of the object directly? And avoid duplicating data that way? Also why don't you have to use the address of operator (&) when setting variables (why isn't it `string = &@"bye"`)? Thank you for your answers and patience.

Comment: (well - I enjoy it :)). You don't need to add the `&` because the assignment already assigns the address of the NSString @"bye" (as in C `const char * str_p = "abc"` holds the address of "abc" I don't understand what do you mean by second address though...

Answer (score 3):

> When an app is running how is the location of pointers kept track of?

Pointers are stored as any other variable; they typically take the same size as an `unsigned long`, but this is by no means guaranteed, just to give you an idea of how they are implemented. Compilers are free to do a huge variety of optimizations, so the pointers may be stored in memory, they may be stored in registers, or they may exist only as hypothetical entities if they are *optimized away*.

Consider the following code:

```
void foo(void) {
    char *c;
    char buf[100];
    for (c=buf; c < buf+100; c++ {
        c = '0';
    }
}
```

In this case, the variable `c` is being used to write an ASCII `0` character to every character in the `buf` array. `c` may exist only in a register, because it does not live beyond this function. (There are better ways of writing this code.)

Consider the following code:

```
struct foo {
    char name[10];
    struct foo *next;
}
```

The member `next` in this case is a pointer to further `struct foo` objects -- say, a linked list of these things. These pointers *must* be stored in memory, because they are part of the contract of these objects -- they have to be there. There is no way around these pointers, either -- the objects they point to can be replaced with other objects on the programmer's whim. And, since the number of these objects is determined entirely at runtime, the compiler can't just keep track of the addresses in its [symbol tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table), as it would for stack-allocated variables.

> So how would I go about changing directly the object stored at the address held by the pointer?

This is complicated by your example's use of `"foo"` strings in the code. These are saved in read-only memory in the process address space, so you cannot modify them. (Surprise!) If you initialize the strings with another method, you can modify the data via the pointer:

```
char *c = malloc(10);
strcpy(c, "hello");
c[0] = 'H';
printf("c: %s\n", c);
```

This will overwrite the `h` with `H` in the allocated space available via the `c` pointer. Accessing pointers as if they were arrays is the same re-writing the pointer access like this:

```
c[0] = 'f';
c+0 = 'f';
```

And, in fact, array accesses are pretty similar -- the name of the array is the same as a pointer to its first element.

It's a little complicated; the book [Expert C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131774298) covers pointers in astonishing detail and is well worth the money.

Answer (score 0):

Q : So how would I go about changing directly the object stored at the address held by the pointer?

Ans : start using **NSMutableString** if you want to change the content of memory location pointed by the your string pointer.

NSString is inmutable type ie you can't change the content but you can make the pointer to point somewhere else. "hello" to "bye" in your case.